# Opengl shapes not drawing in callback function

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, drawing

In my opengl program, I want to make the screen turn red when a user hits a certain key. In my `my_keyboard` function, I have the following:

```
void my_keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
    int feedback_code=0;
    if (key == 49) {
        feedback_code=1;
    }
    if (feedback_code==1) {
        flash_screen();
    }
```

My flash_screen method is as follows:

```
void screen_flash() {
    float mat[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mat);

    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 640.0f);
    glVertex2f(888.0f, 640.f);
    glVertex2f(888.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}
```

By the `glGetFloatv` call, I know that my transformation matrix is back at the lower left corner where it should be, at point (0,0). So the draw function should draw a red square 888x640px, the size of my window. When I run the program and hit the '1' key, however, I don't get a shape! I've used breakpoints and determined that the GlBegin-GlEnd statements DO run, they just don't seem to produce anything.

The only other shapes I have are done in my main display function, called before the main_loop starts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"By the glGetFloatv call, I know that my transformation matrix is back at the lower left corner where it should be, at point (0,0)"_ this is not true. By `glGetFloatv` you are storing your current modelview matrix into `mat`, nothing else. Are you sure you are setting the right projection and modelview matrices?

Comment: If my `mat` shows the identity matrix, which is what I want in this case, wouldn't that mean that my current transformation matrix is at (0,0)?

Based on the drawing I do in my main display function, my projection and modelview matrices are correct. Unless something happens to them when you enter the main loop, which I don't think does.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common newbie mistake. So here's the general rule: *Never make OpenGL drawing calls from event handlers. Never!*

When you want something on the screen happen in reaction to a input event, set some flag variables, and signal a redraw. Then in the drawing function draw according to the signal.